# Is it possible reduce the watt consumption of a 12 VDC radiator fan by using a motor controller?

Tags: motor

[This fan](https://www.ebay.com/itm/16-inch-Universal-Slim-Fan-Push-Pull-Electric-Radiator-Cooling-12V-Mount-Kit-/262118346407) uses 80 watts and, since it is a car radiator fan, it blows alot of air. I need it to run all night on one car battery. It’s fine if it only blows a quarter of its full power, so I am trying to get its consumption down to 20 watts. I have heard talk of motor controllers and was wondering if one would do such a job?

[image: Image of fan]

Comment: Sure thing. Make sure you have a motor controller capable of 80 W though

Answer (score 1):

Buy a DC to DC buck converter from your favourite online market site. There will be plenty of options with an input voltage range that includes 12v. Make sure you get one with at least 7A output current rating, should you wish to use your fan at full voltage / full current. Turn the output voltage down until the fan runs the speed you want.